# Vaadin UI.access() in Tomcat 8.0.21

Tags: java, tomcat, vaadin, push

I have the following code working as expected when I deploy my application in Tomcat 8.0.52:

```
button.addClickHandler(() -> {
    UI ui = UI.getCurrent();

    ui.access(() -> {
      spinner.setVisible(true);
    });
    ui.push();

    try
    {
      Thread.sleep(5000);           
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e)
    {
      LOG.error("", e)
    }  
    spinner.setVisible(false);
});
```

The `Runnable` given to `ui.access()` shows a spinner and after 5 seconds the spinner is hidden.

When I deploy the application in Tomcat 8.0.21 the `Runnable` is not executed because the spinner is not shown.

My UI is annotated with `@Push(value = PushMode.MANUAL, transport = Transport.WEBSOCKET_XHR)`

The Push is working fine in both Tomcat versions, the problem is with the `access()` method of the `UI`.

Any idea about why `ui.access()` is not working in Tomcat 8.0.21?

Comment: Inside the clickhandler you don't need the `ui.access` code, since this is already done by the framework. You need to create a separate thread which then does the stuff async to the clickHandler method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way your example code is written is not supposed to work. If it works, then it only works by accident because of something else not behaving as expected.

Regardless of which Tomcat version you're using, `ui.push()` will trigger running the task that was scheduled using `ui.access()`. You can confirm this by setting a breakpoint or by making the callback print something to the log. The difference between the two Tomat versions is most likely related to how `ui.push()` otherwise behaves when run directly inside a click handler.

`ui.push()` is supposed to be used from inside `ui.access()` tasks that are run in background threads to immediately send any pending changes to the client. In this case, the method isn't called from background thread but instead from a request thread (i.e. the click handler). Furthermore, sleeping on a request thread is problematic for many other reasons as well.

Instead, the structure of your code should directly set the spinner as visible, then schedule a thread or timer for doing the rest of the work and finally return eagerly from the click handler. The thread or timer should then use `ui.access()` for hiding the spinner. Using `ui.push()` would not be needed as long as you're using the default "automatic" push mode instead of `PushMode.MANUAL`.

Comment: I misunderstood the `ui.access()` method. I thought that it creates a new thread to access the UI.